# How to install application on Windows 10 exclusively for users with a normal account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, uac, user

I have installation for app(.exe) file and when i run it, it displays **Yellow User Account Control** dialog.

But i don't know and I can't find way to run this installation file and install the application so it will be **exclusively for users  with a normal account**. I am logged in as **Local Account-Administrator**. So i want to run the .exe installation and install the application exclusively for users  with a normal account so the yellow dialog is not displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deactivate the UAC for this application by (note this will make it run with admin rights, not with the rights of the user. This is needed in order not to show the UAC):

- In Task Scheduler, right-click "Task Scheduler Library" and select "New Folder" Name it whatever you would like.
- Select the new folder and click "Create Task" (not "Create Basic Task")
- Name the task something descriptive. Enable "Run with highest privileges," and select your OS under "Configure for."
- Under the Actions tab, select "Start a program" in the Action dropdown if it isn't already. Click Browse and find your app's .exe file (usually under Program Files on your C: drive).
- (Laptops) Under Conditions tab, deselect "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power."
- On your desktop, right click and select New > Shortcut.
- Paste 'C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "Name of folder\Name of task" into the text box.

[Source](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-eliminate-uac-prompts-for-specific-applications-493128966)

Comment: thank you so much. it worked

Comment: This makes it run as admin. Is this the desired result?

Comment: @harrymc is there an alternative if the applications requires admin rights?

Comment: Just asking if that's the requirement.